# Double background-image in footer tag isuee

Tags: html, css, background-image, footer, linear-gradients

I have a problem with a property `background-image` in the footer tag . I use a double background: the first layer is a stripe pattern , the second gradient generated through property `-linear-gradient-`. In the section the header and body works fine ( I'm using the same mechanism ). I'm using the bootstrap framework.

My HTML:

```
<footer class="text-center">Baron &#8482; New Website Menager Platform</footer>
```

My CSS code :

```
footer {
    margin-top:20px;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    background-color:#111111;
    background:url(../images/stripe-pattern-footer.png) center repeat, linear-gradient(to top, #2B2A2B 0%, #111111 100%);
    background:url(../images/stripe-pattern-footer.png) center repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2B2A2B 0%, #111111 100%);
    background:url(../images/stripe-pattern-footer.png) center repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2B2A2B 0%, #111111 100%);
    background:url(../images/stripe-pattern-footer.png) center repeat, -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2B2A2B 0%, #111111 100%);
    background:url(../images/stripe-pattern-footer.png) center repeat, -o-linear-gradient(top, #2B2A2B 0%, #111111 100%);
    background:url(../images/stripe-pattern-footer.png) center repeat, -khtml-linear-gradient(top, #2B2A2B 0%, #111111 100%);
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 -3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .70);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .70);
    box-shadow: 0 -3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .70);
}
```

Please help or provide clarification.

Ok i find solution of this problem - it was wrong url construct.

Comment: Please provide a `HTML` or Fiddle.

Comment: Html is realy simple <footer class="text-center">Baron &#8482; New Website Menager Platform</footer>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be an issue with the footer.png you are using. You may be not including it or have a spelling error when naming it or the path may be incorrect.

I created a jsfiddle with the code you provided and used a css pattern - it works fine.

```
background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAICAYAAADA+m62AAAAPElEQVQYV2NkQAP/gYARCNDFUQRgirAphitEl0TngxXisg5ZnBGXIpgbYfIYjkb3BNxGbBLYxIgyEaQRAA8KKAWYsZtjAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) center repeat, linear-gradient(to top, #2B2A2B 0%, #111111 100%);
```

**JSFIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/LWDT5/